# Trouble with PUT/GET in Riak testing

Tags: riak

I'm working on a little e2 application that needs to put/get data 
to/from riak. I apparently have a misunderstanding
about some things.

I can successfully put and get key-value pairs to a bucket using the 
erlang client. However, when I try to curl the
data out, I get nothing. In fact, doing:

```
curl -X GET 
"http://riak1:8098/riak?buckets=true" returns '{"buckets":[]}'.
Ditto for curl -X GET "http://192.168.29.11:8098/buckets?buckets=true"
```

In my application, though, I can do this:

```
8> Object = riakc_obj:new(<<"testbucket">>, <<"testkey">>, 
<<"testdata">>). {riakc_obj,<<"testbucket">>,<<"testkey">>,undefined,[],
            undefined,<<"testdata">>}
9> riakc_pb_socket:put(Pid, Object).
ok
10> riakc_pb_socket:get(Pid, <<"testbucket">>, <<"testkey">>).
{ok,{riakc_obj,<<"testbucket">>,<<"testkey">>,
<<107,206,97,96,96,96,204,96,202,5,82,28,202,156,255,126,
                  238,185,94,62,53,131,41,...>>,
                [{{dict,2,16,16,8,80,48,
                        {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...},
                        {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...}}},
                  <<"testdata">>}],
                undefined,undefined}}
11> riakc_pb_socket:list_buckets(Pid).
{ok,[<<"tb1">>,<<"testbucket">>]}
```

So what is the difference between the two? How can I use curl (or any 
other client) to see the buckets, and retrieve
data?

--
Note that this was also sent to the [riak-user mailing list](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2015-January/thread.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had another instance of Riak running on the machine where my application was running, and the app was defaulting to "localhost" when connecting to Riak, rather than connecting to my test cluster.

The data was written correctly, just to the wrong instance.